# How to add javascript expression's output to my CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, less

Is there any way to throw a javascript expression's output (which is a series of classes) into the CSS generated by LESS?
For example, i want to output:

```
.grid_1 { .grd(1); } .grid_2 { .grd(2); } .grid_3 { .grd(3); } .grid_4 { .grd(4); } .grid_5 { .grd(5); } .grid_6 { .grd(6); } .grid_7 { .grd(7); } .grid_8 { .grd(8); } .grid_9 { .grd(9); } .grid_10 { .grd(10); } .grid_11 { .grd(11); } .grid_12 { .grd(12); }
```

......by including this code in LESS:

```
`(function(b){var a="";for(i=1;i<b;i++)a+=".grid_"+i+" { .grd("+i+"); }\n";return a})(12)`;
```

Comment: Expanded form of the js:
        (function(columns){
        var out='';
        for(i=1;i<columns+1;i++){
        out+=".grid_"+i+" { .grd("+i+"); }\n";
        }
        return out;
        })(12);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible with LESS. The extent of the [JavaScript evaluation](http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation) appears to just work for variables and CSS properties.

Comment: Yup. That seems true. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I wish it did work though. It would make things like grids so much easier to generate. Maybe it will be implemented at some point. You could possibly drop it into [GitHub issues](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues) if you really wanted it.